How to mask/hide URL with Nginx Proxy Manager?
First of all, thanks in advance for taking some of your time to read this.
I would like to get some help.
I'm using Nginx Proxy Manager Proxy Hosts option to convert this: http://10.0.0.10:3001/status/monitor into this https://status.com/status/monitor
It works fine.
But I would like to know how to change this so that when I visit https://status.com it shows http://10.0.0.10:3001/status/monitor but that the address bar url still shows https://status.com which is something I'm not sure how to call. Maybe url mask?
I tried adding this to the Advanced tab:
location =  / {
 return 302 /status/monitor;
}

But when I do that and I visit https://status.com the address bar url shows as https://status.com/status/monitor which is not what I want.
I also tried adding this to the Advanced tab:
location / {
 proxy_pass http://status.com/status/monitor;
}

But the same thing happens. The address bar url shows as http://status.com/status/monitor
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!
